# Live Mesh starts exactly once on fresh Win7 Ultimate installation

Tags: windows-7, windows-live-mesh

I did a fresh install of Windows 7 Ulimate 64-bit on a formatted drive on a refurbed Lenovo PC, applied all 102 (!) windows updates, windows seems to be working fine.  No quirks installing, no apps, no junkware, just straight, legal, Win7 Ultimate right from an unopened 2009 Microsoft box.

Ok, breathe sigh -- Install Live Mesh (no messenger, no mail, no writer, no photo, none of the rest of the Windows Live freeware).  Set up my shares, let it run overnight.

watch MOE.exe in the Task-Manager perf pane to make sure it's all settled down.

reboot.

Ok, check that MOE is running and files are getting updated properly from other machines in the mesh. Great.

HOWEVER -- when I try to launch Windows Live Mesh app from the Start jewel, I get a brief hourglass, then nothing.  Reboot.  Same story.

result -- the shares I already posted seem to be synching properly, but I can't run the app, so I can't add and delete shares.  The background process MOE seems to run, but I can't get the app going.

btw, the reason I did this fresh install is I had exactly the same experience running Vista, so I wiped the machine hoping it would solve this nasty problem.  Imagine my surprise!

Will be grateful for clues, advice, etc, please & thanks!

Comment: IS MOE running under your user account or under a different account?  I believe it only runs once on the machine.  It's possible UAC or something else is preventing you from launching the console.

Comment: good hint -- i'll check and get back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the lower right-hand corner of the task bar is an up-arrow ... if you hover over it, it says "Show hidden icons."  Left click it, and inside is a Live-Mesh icon. Right-click the icon, and there is a menu option to "Open Windows Live Mesh."

A lot of voodoo needed to open the app, but the "Run as administrator" technique in my prior answer stopped working.  This seems to be the only way to get it going, now.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Live Mesh outputs log files to the directory:

> C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows Live Mesh

You could parse those logs to see if anything looks fishy.

Answer (score 0):

Run as Admin did the trick.  Hint from Mike :)  Thanks

Comment: you are most welcome...

Comment: Interesting point -- you must actually do this with the Shift-Control Left-Click on-the-icon hack.  You can't do it with the right-click run-as-administrator hack.  I have no idea why, but if I shift-control left-click then Live Mesh runs as admin and works.  If I right-click run-as-admin, Live Mesh console does not run.

Comment: This no longer works as of some Windows Update from the last few weeks.